# Transforming dates in R for clustering

Tags: r, date, cluster-analysis

I have a list of following up dates, given in the following form: year-month-day.
To be able to cluster my data based on these dates, I want to transform the dates into hours. This in a way that the first day in line is 0, the second day 24, the third day 48 etc.

By what code is this possible?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example we can work with.

Comment: maybe `as.numeric(dates - min(dates)) * 24`?

Comment: For instance this list of dates:
2016-09-01

2016-09-01

2016-09-01

2016-09-02

2016-09-02

2016-09-03

2016-09-03

2016-09-04

2016-09-05

2016-09-05

2016-09-05

2016-09-05

2016-09-06

2016-09-07

etc

Comment: First convert them using `as.Date()`. Then you can just subtract them from the first date and get the difference in days

Comment: How can this be done directly for the total column? Namely, the data has 200 lines of different dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
dates<-c('2016-09-01', '2016-09-01', '2016-09-01', '2016-09-02', '2016-09-02', '2016-09-03', '2016-09-03', '2016-09-04', '2016-09-05', '2016-09-05', '2016-09-05', '2016-09-05', '2016-09-06', '2016-09-07')
```

Given the above dates as character strings, convert them to `Date`:

```
dates<-as.Date(dates,format = '%Y-%m-%d')
dates
# [1] "2016-09-01" "2016-09-01" "2016-09-01" "2016-09-02" "2016-09-02" "2016-09-03" "2016-09-03" "2016-09-04" "2016-09-05"
#[10] "2016-09-05" "2016-09-05" "2016-09-05" "2016-09-06" "2016-09-07"
```

Then, simply subtract from the minimum/first date:

```
hrs<-as.numeric(dates-min(dates))*24
hrs
# [1]   0   0   0  24  24  48  48  72  96  96  96  96 120 144
```

Or first date:

```
hrs<-as.numeric(dates-dates[1])*24
hrs
# [1]   0   0   0  24  24  48  48  72  96  96  96  96 120 144
```